# Pulsar Client Error - Failed to load an authentication plugin

Tags: apache-pulsar

when attempting to run pulsar-client consume command locally, I'm getting the error:

> Failed to load an authentication plugin

This is the command I ran:

`./pulsar-client consume persistent://data-log/ingest/data-log-kafka -s damo`

I have a `client.conf` configured, and the full "stack trace" from pulsar is listed below. I can't see what I am missing

```
    Failed to load an authentication plugin
    Usage: pulsar-client [options] [command] [command options]
    Options:
    --auth-params
       Authentication parameters, e.g., "key1:val1,key2:val2".
       Default: token:eyJh##############################
    --auth-plugin
       Authentication plugin class name.
       Default: org.apache.pulsar.client.impl.auth.AuthenticationToken 
    -h, --help
       Show this help.
       Default: false
    --url
       Broker URL to which to connect.
       Default: pulsar+ssl://aaa-bbb-ccc-ms-tls.acme.com:6651
    Commands:
    consume      Consume messages from a specified topic
      Usage: consume [options] TopicName
        Options:
          --hex
             Display binary messages in hex.
             Default: false
          -n, --num-messages
             Number of messages to consume, 0 means to consume forever.
             Default: 1
          -r, --rate
             Rate (in msg/sec) at which to consume, value 0 means to consume
             messages as fast as possible.
             Default: 0.0
        * -s, --subscription-name
             Subscription name.
          -t, --subscription-type
             Subscription type: Exclusive, Shared, Failover.
             Default: Exclusive
             Possible Values: [Exclusive, Shared, Failover]
```

Any tips appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was I was on old version of pulsar, and works fine on 2.5.0. d'oh!!!!